# Not Trimming white spaces from a string in c#

Tags: c#

`Trim()` Function Not Working Please Help its not trimming the white space.

```
string samplestring = "172-6573-4955";  
string[] array = samplestring .Split('-');
string firstElem = array.First();
string restOfArray = string.Join(" ", array.Skip(1));
array[1] = restOfArray.Trim(); // providing value "6573 4955"
```

The scenario is I am splitting string and merging 2nd and last index into one but it's merging with white spaces.

Comment: You are join with empty space `string.Join(" ", rest..)`, so white space will be always added. Replace it wtih `""`, or use aggregate function. What's more, `Trim` removes only leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @Soner Gönül String.Empty as someone suggested is better in performance ? Yes that was ultimate problem working smoothly thank you! Indeed but can someone randomly generate white spaces between whenever that string.join method call ? target is it should sometimes put spaces sometimes it doesn't randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trim()` removes whitespace from the front and back of a string, not in the middle. The whitespaces in the middle are being inserted by the `" "` provided as the parameter to `Join()` method. You could provide `string.empty` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Trim is used to remove all leading and trailing white-space. And you want to trim the white space from middle. You may try like this:

```
string restOfArray = string.Join("", array.Skip(1));
```

or better:

```
string restOfArray = string.Join(string.Empty, array.Skip(1));
```

instead of

```
string restOfArray = string.Join(" ", array.Skip(1));
```

Comment: @ShahAbdullah:- String.Empty will handle that as well!

Comment: @ShahAbdullah:- If that helped for you then you may accept it as an answer so that it may help others in future!

Comment: Done that @R.T. one thing more can we put random character in place of white spaces whenever this function is called 

string _restofArray = string.Join(RandomCharactor, array.Skip(1)); // Populate random string on each call.

Comment: @ShahAbdullah:- You can give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Trim is working as expected. Taken from [String.Trim Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the
>   current String object.

The possible solutions for you are :

```
string restOfArray = string.Join(string.Empty, array.Skip(1));
```

Or

```
 array[1] = restOfArray.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

To just split the first n-let from the rest use an additional array or you will end up with spurious data. And join with the correct separator you used in split(`-`):

```
string restOfArray = string.Join("-", array.Skip(1));
string[] result = new string[] { firstElem, restOfArray };
```

You don't need `Trim()`.

You can simplify your code this way:

```
string[] splitCode(string code)
{
    string[] segments;

    segments = code.Split('-');

    return new string[] { segments.First(), string.Join("-", segments.Skip(1)) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim really isn't need here; you can simply split the string and join the parts you want:

```
string source = "172-6573-4955";  
string[] splitter = new string[] {"-"};
string[] result;
result = source.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
string final = (result[1] + result[2]);
Console.Write(final);
```

Result:

**`65734955`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string samplestring = "172-6573-4955";
string[] array = samplestring.Split(new char[] {'-'},2);
string result = array[1].Replace("-","");
```

Also, for your question about randomly putting spaces, can u pls explain "randomly" here.